# Нормальный ответ или голосовать за удаление, а вопрос закрывать по причине "больше не воспроизводится"?

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, закрытие-вопросов, ответы, самоответы

В очереди часто встречаю подобные вопросы: [Modx 2.6 Вопрос по выводу переменных в чанки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/875385/15479)

Как в таком случае поступать? Обычно ошибка кроется в каких-то мелочах. В плане полезности в целом такой вопрос смысла особого не несёт.

Как вы поступаете? Отмечаете такие ответы в очереди как "Это не ответ, нужно внести правку в вопрос", а потом голосуете за закрытие как "проблема решена"? Или считаете, что такие ответы нормальны?

Answer (score 6):

Каждый случай нужно рассматривать отдельно:

1. если ошибка была в опечатке - нужно закрыть с соответствующей причиной
2. если ошибка просто перестала воспроизводиться - нужно закрыть с соответствующей причиной
3. если в ответе приведены конкретные действия по устранению ошибки (кроме опечаток), либо дано описание причины ошибки - ничего не нужно делать, так как дан ответ на вопрос.

---

Если рассматривать ответ из вопроса, то можно было и не удалять, так как на вопрос "Почему не выводится значение?" дан вполне нормальный ответ "Значение не выводится, так как переменная не заполнена."

Comment: К приведённым пунктам особо добавить и нечего) А вопрос в итоге попал в модераторскую очередь и был мной преобразован в правку, после чего вопрос я закрыл и удалил. На мой взгляд пользы от него особой не было. Вот если б было больше каких-то подробностей и деталей в ответе - можно было б оставить.